# Prolog: Recursive Multiplication of 2 Numbers

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I don't understand why this recursive definition of a multiplication is working.
I get the add part, but how is the value of "A" in this context.
The code is the following:

```
add(0,X,X).
add(s(X),Y,Z):-add(X,s(Y),Z).

mult(0,X,0).
mult(s(X),Y,Z):-mult(X,Y,A), add(Y,A,Z).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, `A` is the value of `(X-1) * Y`. You find this value recursively with the `mult` rule then add it to `Y` in the `add` rule to get your final result. It is writing the multiplication as `X * Y = (X - 1) * Y + Y`

Really what ends up happening is it calls `add` `X` times, and each of those times it adds `Y` to the final result (starting from zero). This is exploiting multiplication as repeated addition. Here is a trace by hand:

1. `mult(3, 2, Z)`
   Initial call
2. `mult(2, 2, A_1), add(2, A_1, Z)`
   Subtract 1 fram `X`
3. `mult(1, 2, A_2), add(2, A_2, A_1)`
   Again.
4. `mult(0, 2, A_3), add(2, A_3, A_2)`
   One last time
5. `mult(0, 2, A_3)`
   Only one possibility, as zero cannot match `s(x)`. `A_3` is set to 0.
6. `mult(0, 2, 0), add(2, 0, A_2)`
   Step 4, but with `A_3` substituted. We now know that `A_2` must be 2.
7. `mult(1, 2, 2), add(2, 2, A_1)`
   Step 3, but with `A_2` substituted. We now know `A_1` must be 4.
8. `mult(2, 2, 4), add(2, 4, Z)`
   Step 2, but with `A_1` substituted.  We now know `Z` must be 6, the final result.

For steps 2 through 4 you are counting downward as a way of finding the number of times you need to repeat the addition operation. Step 5 is the base case, starting the final result at zero. In steps 6 through 8 you carry out the addition. This gives the result of `Z = 6 = 2 + 2 + 2`

Comment: great answer! very nice for helping me to learn the way think recurevly.

Answer (score 5):

To understand the predicates, try to "read" what they are saying.

Reading the `add/3` definition first...

```
add(0,X,X).
```

> Adding `0` to `X` results in `X`.

```
add(s(X),Y,Z):-add(X,s(Y),Z).
```

> Adding `s(X)` (the successor of `X`) to `Y` results in `Z` *if* adding `X` to `s(Y)` (the successor of `Y`) results in `Z`.

If we view *successor* as adding 1, then this is saying `(X + 1) + Y` results in `Z` if `X + (Y + 1)` results in `Z`. That's logically obvious, but doesn't seem to go anywhere. However, we'll note that this logic is closely coupled with the base case of `add(0,X,X)` since the recursive case will *reduce* the first argument by removing a single succession each iteration until the first argument becomes `0`.

Now let's try `mult/3`...

```
mult(0,X,0).
```

> Multiplying `0` by `X` results in `0`

This seems to be obvious.

```
mult(s(X),Y,Z):-mult(X,Y,A), add(Y,A,Z).
```

> Multiplying the successor of `X` by `Y` results in `Z` *if* multiplying `X` by `Y` results in `A`, *and* adding `Y` to `A` results in `Z`.

If you think of *successor* as adding 1, then this is saying that `(X+1)*Y` is `Z` if `X*Y` is `A` and `A+Y` is `Z`. This would make sense since `(X+1)*Y` is `(X*Y)+Y` which would be `A+Y`.

Comment: great! helped a lot. it is another way to handle prolog problems. i wished i could vote it up, but i cant.